# How to redirect pbpbb3 SEO to bbPress

Tags: seo, phpbb3, bbpress

How to configure htaccess to permanently redirect all the urls of a PHPBB3 SEO premod (phpbb seo) to a new installation of bbPress?

The old forum has http://www.battlefield-france.com/forum and the new one has https://www.battlefield-france.com/beta/forum/

**UPDATE:**

In the PHPBB3 HTACCESS:

```
# You may need to un-comment the following lines
# Options +FollowSymlinks
# To make sure that rewritten dir or file (/|.html) will not load dir.php in case it exist
# Options -MultiViews
# REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
RewriteEngine On
# Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
# HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
# This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
# RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
# REWRITE BASE
RewriteBase /forum/
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO FORCE CANONICAL DOMAIN
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^battlefield-france\.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.battlefield-france.com/forum/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
#####################################################
# PHPBB SEO REWRITE RULES ALL MODES
#####################################################
# AUTHOR : dcz www.phpbb-seo.com
# STARTED : 01/2006
#################################
# FORUMS PAGES
###############
# FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. "forum" REQUIRES TO BE SET AS FORUM INDEX
# RewriteRule ^forum\.html$ index.php [QSA,L,NC]
# FORUM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
# TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
# PHPBB FILES ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^ressources/[a-z0-9_-]+/(thumb/)?([0-9]+)$ download/file.php?id=$2&t=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# PROFILES THROUGH USERNAME
RewriteRule ^membre/([^/]+)/?$ memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&un=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# USER MESSAGES THROUGH USERNAME
RewriteRule ^membre/([^/]+)/(topics|posts)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ search.php?author=$1&sr=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# GROUPS ALL MODES
RewriteRule ^(groupe|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
# POST
RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+)\.html$ viewtopic.php?p=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# ACTIVE TOPICS
RewriteRule ^sujets-actifs(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNANSWERED TOPICS
RewriteRule ^sans-reponses(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# NEW POSTS
RewriteRule ^nouveaux-messages(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
# UNREAD POSTS
RewriteRule ^non-lu(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
# THE TEAM
RewriteRule ^equipe\.html$ memberlist.php?mode=leaders [QSA,L,NC]
# HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES

#####################################################
# GYM Sitemaps & RSS
# Global channels
RewriteRule ^rss(/(news)+)?(/(digest)+)?(/(short|long)+)?/?$ gymrss.php?channels&$2&$4&$6 [QSA,L,NC]
# HTML Global news & maps
RewriteRule ^(news|maps)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ map.php?$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
# END GYM Sitemaps & RSS
#####################################################

# FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
# THESE THREE LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
RewriteRule ^.+/(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|download/file.php)$ $1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
RewriteRule ^.+/(styles/.*|images/.*)/$ $1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
# END PHPBB PAGES
#####################################################

#####################################################
# GYM Sitemaps & RSS
# HTML Module additional modes
RewriteRule ^(news|maps)/([a-z0-9_-]+)(/([a-z0-9_-]+))?/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ map.php?$2=$4&$1&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
# Main feeds & channels
RewriteRule ^rss(/(news)+)?(/(digest)+)?(/(short|long)+)?(/([a-z0-9_-]+))?/([a-z0-9_]+)\.xml(\.gz)?$ gymrss.php?$9=$8&$2&$4&$6&gzip=$10 [QSA,L,NC]
# Module feeds
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9_-]*-[a-z]{1,2}([0-9]+)(/(news)+)?(/(digest)+)?(/(short|long)+)?/([a-z0-9_]+)\.xml(\.gz)?$ gymrss.php?$8=$1&$3&$5&$7&gzip=$9 [QSA,L,NC]
# Module feeds without ids
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)(/(news)+)?(/(digest)+)?(/(short|long)+)?/([a-z0-9_]+)\.xml(\.gz)?$ gymrss.php?nametoid=$1&$3&$5&$7&modulename=$8&gzip=$9 [QSA,L,NC]
# Google SitemapIndex
RewriteRule ^sitemapindex\.xml(\.gz)?$ sitemap.php?gzip=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
# Module cat sitemaps
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9_-]+-([a-z]{1,2})([0-9]+)\.xml(\.gz)?$ sitemap.php?module_sep=$1&module_sub=$2&gzip=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
# Module sitemaps
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)-([a-z0-9_-]+)\.xml(\.gz)?$ sitemap.php?$1=$2&gzip=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
# END GYM Sitemaps & RSS
#####################################################
```

In the Wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /beta/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Including code samples detailing what you've tried will increase the likelihood of a response.

Comment: Ok, so I though to simply redirect the entire sitemap where all the urls are redirected as: redirectpermanent old_url new_url But that's not the best solution, I guess...